# 2D array shift up or down for column for square matrix

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I know how to shift the row of the 2d array of type double
where i is the matrix size

```
public static void rowshiftRight(int i, double[][] array) {
        int m = array[i].length;
        double temp = array[i][m-1];
        for (int k=m-1; k>=1; k--){
            array[i][k] = array[i][k-1];
        }
        array[i][0] = temp;
    }
```

I'm trying to change the above logic to shiftcolum, any help will be grateful

```
//wrong code
public static void colshiftdownorup(int i, double[][] array) {
        int m = array.length;
        double temp = array[m-1][i];
        for (int k=m-1; k>=1; k--){
            array[k][i] = array[k-1][i];
        }
        array[i][0] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by some answers and the working of your question. By "row" you mean horizontal section of a table like structure right? You can't shift a row "right" but you can shift it "up" or "down". You can shift _columns_ left and right. Or do you use the reverse definition?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to shift a column you will need some extra checks since 2D arrays are not always perfect matrices, e.g.:

`int[][] array = new int[4][];` might be like this

```
2 3 4 5
1 1 1    
1 2    
1 2 3 4
```

If you want to shift 3rd column (4,1,null,3) you will see the extra work required to control null values.

Comment: Thanks, if it's for square matrix? then :) anyway I will try my best, it's for one coding challenge I don't have enough time :(

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be at the last line of `colshiftRight`

Change :

```
array[i][0] = temp;
```

to :

```
array[0][i] = temp;
```

You may also want to rename the method to `colshiftDown`